# Compare hazard ratios of a meta analysis

Tags: meta-analysis, hazard

A meta-analysis reports that the hazard ratio of a prognostic marker A for predicting mortality in heart failure is 12.5 (95% CI 6.2 - 26.1) and the hazard ratio of a prognostic marker B is 3.2 (95% CI 2.2 - 5.1). Can we conclude that A is better prognostic marker than B?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.